# Html for put a label in bottom of an image

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone I'm newbie in this world of software, and now I have a problem, I need put a label in bottom of an image,  I thought  that I could make this, but after along time I decide put my problem in this site, for an orientation
my idea was created a HTML table y put tag img but later my problem is how I can put a label over the tag img

```
<table border="2px"> 
      <td><img src="tiquet.png" height="150" width="90"></td> 
 </table>
```

I can't found a HTML tag for put a label in bottom of an image, then
I thought in make another table for put into the another table but I think this not a good idea because how I can align the label  with the bottom of image 
do you have some idea  that  could be great help for me.

Comment: By label you mean caption, right?

Comment: yes, I need know how I can put some text over this image

Comment: Posted the answer. Have a look. :-)

Answer (score 20):

You can use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements to achieve the desired affect. You can use some CSS to set the border width for the figure element.

```
<figure>
    <img src="tiquet.png" height="150" width="90">
    <figcaption>Your label goes here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: thanks, superimpose text over image to look like a single image with a text, it's like a ticket  and above with a  text that would be a price,
so I need to create this effect

Comment: In that case, this answer does not apply. You can have a look here => https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Answer (score 2):

Try as follows

**html:-**

```
 <a href="http://name.com">
        <img src="name.png" width="100px" height="100px"> 
        <div class="caption">Caption here</div>
    </a>
```

**css:-**

```
#images{
    text-align:center;
    margin:50px auto; 
}
#images a{
    margin:0px 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
 }
```

Comment: thanks, superimpose text over image to look like a single image with a text, it's like a ticket  and above with a  text that would be a price,
so I need to create this effect